# How to reset Ion-Select form field in Ionic 3?

Tags: angular, forms, ionic3, ion-select

I want to present an option to allow user to clear the `ion-select` form field if they decided to not select an option after already selecting, but I'm having a hard time finding anything to help out.

```html
<ion-item class="formField ionField">
        <ion-label color="primary" stacked>PROJECT</ion-label>
        <ion-select
          #projectName
          ngModel
          name="project"
          interface="action-sheet">
          <ion-option (ionSelect)="projectSelect(project.ProjectName,i)" [value]={ID:project.ID,Name:project.ProjectName} *ngFor="let project of projectArray; let i = index" >{{project.ProjectName}}</ion-option>
        </ion-select>
      </ion-item>
```

Perhaps something like this? Ionic doesn't have any resources for resetting.

```
<ion-option (ionChange)="resetValue()">Reset</ion-option>
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: What about my answer? is it not suit with your requirement ?

Comment: I was wanting to avoid having another ui element on the form to reset, but this will do. Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use `ion-option` to reset `ion-select` form field. But you can provide clear button to reset `ion-select` if an `ion-option` is selected as below.

**HTML**

```
<ion-content padding>

  <ion-list>
  <ion-item>
    <ion-label>PROJECT</ion-label>
    <ion-select [(ngModel)]="project">
      <ion-option *ngFor="let project of projects" value="{{project}}">{{project}}</ion-option>
    </ion-select>
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>

<button *ngIf="project" ion-button (click)="reset()">clear</button>

</ion-content>
```

**TS**

```
export class HomePage {

  projects: any = [];
  project: string;

  constructor() {
    this.projects = ["project 1", "project 2", "project 3", "project 4"];
  }

  reset() {
    this.project = null;
  }
}
```

Find working example [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-zrhj96?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.ts)

Comment: Not working in latest version.

Answer (score 0):

Another option that I figured out is to use two exaclty identical ion-select in parallel with their rendering controlled by ngIf. If the ngModel has value then first ion-select gets rendered, otherwise, second one gets rendered and because while rendering a new ion-select, it will not have any selected option by default, it works perfectly fine for both (null and non-null) ngModel values.